# How to polynomially reduce euclidean tsp to regular tsp?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, traveling-salesman

The normal tsp seems way harder than the euclidean one, is the euclidean tsp np complete? If so is there a simple reduction that gives an answer to the tsp if you have the euclidean tsp algorithm?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Euclidean_TSP and the references is the article

Comment: @adrianN so basically. It is not np complete unless you round distances.

Comment: "Like the general TSP, Euclidean TSP is NP-hard in either case."

Comment: Since there's a PTAS for Euclidian TSP (but, IIRC, not for TSP), you are looking for a reduction from a strongly NP-complete to a weakly NP-complete problem. These are notoriously nasty.

Comment: @Raphael So does that mean there is a reduction we don't know or even if they are related is unknown? If weak np = p does that imply strong np = p?

Comment: Does your definition of TSP require returning to the starting point? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer yes

Comment: We know there is one, and I'm pretty sure somebody has written it down somewhere (maybe you have to chain a couple of reductions). But you are asking for a *simple* reduction, which I don't think exists. But I'm far from an expert in this.

Answer (score 2):

There is not known to be a polynomial reduction from Euclidean TSP to regular TSP, since regular TSP is in [NPO](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N#npo), but Euclidean TSP seems to involve [comparing sums of square-roots](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/4010/6973).

As far as I'm aware, even [PP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#pp)^(P[P^PP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#psharpp)) is not known

to be able to make the necessary comparisons.

"..., is the euclidean tsp np complete?"

For the above reason, it's not even known to be in classes that seem to

be significantly bigger than NP. ​ ​ ​ Furthermore, if it is in NP then ​ NP = coNP ,

since from the minimum tour length in a node-induced finite grid graph,

one can trivially deduce whether-or-not [that graph has a Hamiltonian cycle](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0211056).

"... is there a simple reduction that gives an answer

to the tsp if you have the euclidean tsp algorithm?"

I agree with Raphael that there's probably no *simple* reduction for that.